# Why does C++ sometimes not identify overloaded operators?

Tags: c++

I have been scratching my head at a problem with my program. At lines 4-6, I overload `operator==` to accept an int and a `pair<int,int>`. Then I try it at line 9. It works. So then, I try it at line 10, with find(). It... fails. C++ says that it can't find a `operator==()` overload that accepts an `int` and a `pair<int,int>`, even though I defined one. Can someone figure out what I did wrong? Can someone also  give me a valid version of my program, that isn't to complicated?
The error is message is below:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/stdc++.h:54:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/ccomplex:39:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/complex:45:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/sstream:38:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/istream:38:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/ios:40:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:268:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::pair<int, int>' and 'const int')
        { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

It is quite long and goes on for a long time.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool operator ==(pair<int,int>x , int y){
  return x.second ==y;
}
int main() {
  vector<pair<int,int>>a_vector={{1,2},{2,3}};
  cout<<(a_vector[0]==a_vector[0].second)<<"\n";
  auto found = find(a_vector.begin(),a_vector.end(),a_vector[0].second);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When you are struggling with a compiler error, please add the *exact message* as you get it to your question.

Comment: You have to define both of them, `x==y`, `y==x`.

Comment: @Quimby I tried, and it didn't work. The compiler still failed to recognize my overloaded operator()==

Comment: Your problem is that the version of `std::find()` you're calling takes two iterators and a value  AND requires that the value is convertible to the value type of the iterator.   The iterators in your case are for a `vector<pair<int, int>>` so their value type is `pair<int, int>`.    The net effect is that `std::find()` requires (in your code) `a_vector[0].second` (i.e. an `int`) to be convertible to a `pair<int, int>` which is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I try it at line 9. It works.

Your `main` can see the overload of `operator==` you declared but `std::find`
cannot. The only way for `std::find` to call your operator is through
[argument-dependent lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).
However, ADL won't find your `operator==` because it is not part of the innermost enclosing namespace of `std::pair` (which is `std`).

I recommend you do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool secondEqual (pair<int, int> x, int y) {
//   ^ give it a meaningful name
    return x.second == y;
}

int main() {

    vector<pair<int, int>> avec = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
    cout << secondEqual(avec[0], avec[0].second) << "\n";
    auto found = find_if(avec.begin(), avec.end(), [&](pair<int, int> const& p) {
        return secondEqual(p, avec[0].second);
    });
}
```

I don't encourage you to use:

- `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`;
- `using namespace std`.

---

**Edit:** As noted by [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884116/why-does-c-sometimes-not-identify-overloaded-operators/71884384?noredirect=1#comment127039984_71884384), if you only defined `operator==` to call it in `std::find`, a better solution would be:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int>> avec = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};

    //                   | avec.begin() + 1 (?)
    auto found = find_if(avec.begin(), avec.end(), [&](auto const& p) {
        return p.second == avec[0].second;
    });
}
```

Also, since we're at it, most probably you want to pass `avec.begin() + 1` as `std::find`'s first argument; otherwise `std::find` will always return you an iterator to `avec[0]`.

Comment: There's no need for renaming the operator if you switch to `find_if`– the lambda is in the same namespace as the operator, so *can* find it... Apart from, *if* using a custom lambda I'd rather drop the operator entirely and do the appropriate comparison directly within the lambda.

Comment: Yes, there's no need for `operator==` to be renamed. If OP thinks `operator==` is a meaningful name for `secondEqual`, so be it. I just don't think it is.

Comment: Not sure if 'secondEqual' is that much better either, but that's a matter of oppinion... I guess that the operator has been defined just to be usable with `std::find`, but that failed... If so, best in my eyes is to skip the operator entirely as mentioned already: `std::find_if(..., [&](auto& p) { return p.second == ... }`; if we need it more than once than maybe a functor with appropriate constructor instead.